# Is it possible to control the image quality of png encoding on Android?

Tags: android, image, png

I'm trying to convert a bitmap to PNG with

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outStream);
```

and then share the file. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) `quality` parameter is ignored for PNG format.

Can I control the image quality while converting bitmap to PNG, despite it's a lossless format?

Or should I go with JPEG, taking into account that the image I want to share doesn't have any transparency. On the other hand, some part of the image (about 30-40%) filled with the same color, which is PNG works well with, as far as I know.

Comment: I am not aware that PNG has a concept of a quality factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG doesn't have a quality factor.  PNG compression is lossless (i.e., quality is always 100%).

You can, however, reduce the image quality before handing it to the compressor, by doing thing such as reducing the number of colors and transparency levels, not using anti-aliasing, etc, to make the image data more compressible.

You can also recompress the PNG file afterwards with a separate optimizer such as pngquant, pngcrush, imagemagick/graphicsmagick, zopflipng, or optipng.

Note that imagemagick/graphicsmagick do have a "quality" value for PNG compression, but it has a different meaning than for JPEG files (higher PNG "quality" generally means better compression but no change in image appearance).